# Interface is reported as "Unused element"

Tags: php, interface

I have two interface files, and one is reported as an unused element. This is a Drupal module, with this structure:

```
frog/src/FrogInterface.php
frog/src/ToadInterface.php
```

I made the FrogInterface first:

```
namespace Drupal\frog;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;
use Drupal\user\EntityOwnerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedInterface;

interface FrogInterface extends ContentEntityInterface, EntityOwnerInterface, EntityChangedInterface {

}
```

I then added the ToadInterface:

```
namespace Drupal\frog;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;
use Drupal\user\EntityOwnerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedInterface;

interface ToadInterface extends ContentEntityInterface, EntityOwnerInterface, EntityChangedInterface {

}
```

In phpStorm, ToadInterface give a warning:

```
Unused element: 'ToadInterface'
```

The interface is implemented in
frog/src/Entity/Toadtest.php:

```
namespace Drupal\frog\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedTrait;
use Druoal\frog\ToadInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;

class Toadtest extends ContentEntityBase implements ToadInterface {

}
```

In Toadtest.php, phpStorm reports:

```
Undefined namespace 'frog'
Undefined class 'ToadInterface'
```

And even if I delete FrogInterface.php, ToadInterface and Toadtest still report the errors.

Comment: Are you actually using `ToadInterface` anywhere?

Comment: No - I tried creating a class that imported it, in frog/src/Entity/Toadtest.php, with namespace Drupal\frog|Entity, as "class Toadtest extends ContentEntityBase implementsToadInterface", but I get the error "Undefined namespace frog"

Comment: BTW, I based this on the examples/content_entity_example module, and tried to use the same general syntax. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is your `frog` namespace under `Drupal`?

Comment: Because the file is in modules/custom/frog. Drupal assumes the src subdirectory un Der the module; this is the way other modules namespaces are done.

Comment: I edited the question to show the example.

Comment: You have a typo... `Druoal\frog\ToadInterface` should be `Drupal\frog\ToadInterface`

Comment: That was it! Darned typos. I greatly appreciate your second set of eyes, thanks.